# piping output to an alias

Tags: bash, alias

in order to run a certain command I need to use

```
sudo -h -u someuser <somecommand>
```

in order to save some sanity I created an alias

```
alias somecommand='function _dm(){ sudo -u ubuntu somecommand $@; };_dm'
```

This works great until I try and do something fancy.

```
somecommand arg1 | xargs somecommand arg2
```

This causes me problems since xargs doesn't invoke the alias.  Is it possible to make this work somehow?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're wrapping a function inside the alias, if you could just use the same function directly? [not that it'd help with xargs but still]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As long as your alias is in your `.bashrc`, you should be able to do `...|xargs bash -c somealias ...`
2. Easier is to put your alias in a shell script instead.  Make `~/bin`, add it to your `PATH`, put the script in, and your original command will work.

Example shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u ubuntu somecommand "$@"
```

**Edit**: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/979657/2877364) suggests trying #1 with `bash -ic` rather than `bash -c`.

Comment: The problem I am having with #1 is that I run the command like | xargs bash -c somealias param1  

somealias behaves as if no additional parameters are passed.  Its not seeing the piped in parameters.

Comment: May have to do with the details of `somecommand`.  What about #2?  It's more reliable and more flexible.

Comment: ended up using option 2 with a shell script.  Thanks